# Starting Clonezilla through GNU Grub

Tags: linux, grub, clonezilla, gnu

I have a disc image that I want to install on a new linux computer via Clonezilla. However, when I go to the boot menu and select the USB stick as a booting option, it takes me to the GNU Grub menu and not the Clonezilla option screen. Anyone have an idea of how I can install this disc image on my computer?

Comment: Was the USB disk created as a boot media for Clonezilla? Is it of the same type boot (BIOS/UEFI)?

Comment: I believe so. On the boot screen it is recognized as "UEFI  - USB DISK 3.0". Another note is that on a different Linux computer when I select "UEFI - USB DISK" as a boot option it goes to the yellow Clonezilla page to start the cloning process, but not on this new Z4G4 computer that I actually want to install the disc image on.

Comment: Check perhaps the BIOS settings?

Comment: Sounds like Microsoft not handling GRUB properly, which is normal. The Linux PC you mention would, depending on it being properly installed on the HDD and in the right position, handle GRUB without issue. Windows, not so much. You don't need GRUB frontloaded on the USB stick to load Clonezilla though, at least you shouldn't.

Comment: The usb stick does have a grub file, not sure if that helps or is valuable at all. 
     But some more details - after working with the Grub interface we can check the contents of our USB stick and it does not recognize any files in there besides for a "grub.cfg" file. We can try changing the BIOS settings but I'm not entirely sure what to change...